# Google map marker click, display a modal

Tags: javascript, google-maps, modal-dialog

Hi i need show the bootstrap modal on clicking the marker, the code is here:
[map](http://www.bootply.com/R6RIPwYmTk)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I´ve forked your code here: http://www.bootply.com/NoflZLtYtI

I´ve added the following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_1, 'click', function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Suscribe click event on "marker_1", and in the callback, open modal window!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hola Rubén, decidí ocupar un modal que no es de bootstrap cuando doy click en el marker me abre solo el lightbox ya que el botón que dispara el evento del modal 'show' tiene un data: data-modal="modal-1".