# display a Modal or a dialog when a button is clicked in infowindow in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to display a new modal when a button is clicked in the infowindow. When I click MORE button in info window a modal should appear with more information regarding the marker while disabling the background.

I have tried in the following way but it is not working:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

I have added a button in info window to display the modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

But the above code is not working.

Comment: what is not working? what is happening, what is the expected result, set up a fiddle or sth like this pls, because your code looks fine like  one to one copy from bootstrap doc

Comment: Your code seems fine. Are you sure bootstrap is loaded properly before this code? Please see the code in this example: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal

Comment: i am building dynamic string of html and displaying a customized infowindow using javascript ..so is it possible to display a modal when clicked on a button which is created dynamically in an infowindow

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma..the above code i posted is not working only when the button is in a info window

Comment: can you please give a example in fiddle if you know any using info window in javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439909/google-map-marker-click-display-a-modal This looks like a possible solution for you.